# React CSSTransitionGroup with multiple components

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to build a reusable animated overlay.

However, only the first component mount is detected, meaning that I can only use this overlay once for my whole application. If I use a second one, it won't be animated.

I tried a lot of thing, like using unique keys, transition names and so on, but I can't get this to work.
Here is the current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import styled from 'styled-componets'

const OverlayDiv = styled.div`

transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
&._overlay-transition-appear,
&._overlay-transition-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
&._overlay-transition-appear._loading-overlay-transition-appear-active,
&._overlay-transition-enter._loading-overlay-transition-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
&._overlay-transition-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
&._overlay-transition-leave._loading-overlay-transition-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
`;


const animated = (WrappedComponent) => ({ animate = true, ...otherProps }) => {
  if (animate) {
    return (
      <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="_overlay-transition"
        transitionAppear
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
        transitionAppearTimeout={500}
      >
        <WrappedComponent {...otherProps} />
      </CSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
  return <WrappedComponent {...otherProps} />;
};
export const Overlay = ({ animate = true, className, parentDimensions, children }) => (
  <OverlayDiv
    key="overlay" // import for React CSS Transition
    className={className}
    height={parentDimensions ? `${parentDimensions.offsetHeight}px` : '100%'}
  >
    {children}
  </OverlayDiv>
      );

export default animated(Overlay);
```

Any idea on this ?

Comment: I think it's too much of code for one question. Try to divide it into logical pieces (`styled.div`, `Overlay`, `animated`...) and find which one is not working and ask more specific.

Comment: Hi, those components are tightly bound, because the animation is always made of (verbose) CSS + a wrapper + the actual component, so I prefered to provide everything. 
I can already tell that the CSS and the component aren't faulty (except for the "key" maybe), because this code works when using one component. I simply left them for demo purposes. The issue only appears with multiple components.